# How to get model.isvalid true if an entity has a icollection field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to ASP.Net MVC. When I was trying to add student record, I am getting error *Model.isvalid* is false. In student view, I am giving lastname, firstname and enrollmentdate only. I debugged the code and found that Icollection field is false. here is my code snippet. Please guide me to understand the situation and solve it.

```
public class Student
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("LastName,FirstName,EnrollmentDate")] Student student)
        {
            try
            {
               
                
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    _context.Add(student);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException /* ex */)
            {
                //Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +
                    "Try again, and if the problem persists " +
                    "see your system administrator.");
            }
            return View(student);
        }
```

I tried to remove the `enrollments` field, but i want to know how to proceed with the field in the model

Comment: ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core?

Comment: If you have nullability enabled in your project, try changing that property to be nullable: `ICollection<Enrollment>? Enrollments`.

Comment: ASP.NET Core  MVC Project

Answer (score 0):

> When I was trying to add student record, I am getting error
> Model.isvalid is false. In student view, I am giving lastname,
> firstname and enrollmentdate only. I debugged the code and found that
> Icollection field is false.

Well, based on your scenario and description you are getting the expected error or model validation value.

Because, `ModelState.IsValid` is getting false as your ICollection field in your model set not non-nullable. So when the form value submitted compiler would be treated `ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments` value as required or non-null.

Furthermore, when you create a Student instance in your Create action, the Enrollments property is expected to be initialized. Since you are only providing values for LastName, FirstName, and EnrollmentDate, the Enrollments property will be null by default, and this could be causing the validation failure.

In order to fix your model validation issue, you either can set Enrollments as null `?` or you can assign a defult value in it or even can exclude Enrollments collection.

Let's have a look in practice, how we can achieve that;

Exclude Collection:

```
public class StudentCreateViewModel
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
}
```

Assign Default Value:

```
public class StudentCreateViewModel
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; } = new List<Enrollment>();
}
```

Set Nullability:

```
public class StudentCreateViewModel
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
    ICollection<Enrollment>? Enrollments { get; set; }
}
```

**Note:** Keep in mind, The validation system treats non-nullable parameters or bound properties as if they had a [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]. If the app was built with enable, a missing value for Name in a JSON or form post results in a validation error. Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-8.0#model-state), that would be resourceful for you.